# Safari gives wrong height() property

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have problem with Safari. Gives me wrong height property after using a `.height()` function. Only this one browser works wrong, others gets me correct height.

HTML + CSS:

```
.col-header-content {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="cat-col-wrapper">
    <div class="cat-col-header">
        <div class="col-header-content">
            /* next content DOM with 
               width: 100%; 
               position: relative
               float: left; 
             */
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS FILE:

```
(function($) {    

$(window).load(function(e) {
    _E.Controller();
}

_E = {
    Controller: function() {
         $('.cat-col-wrapper').each(function(index, el) {
              var headerContent = $(this).find('.col-header-content');
              console.log(headerContent.height());
         }
    }
}

}(window.jQuery));
```

When real height of element is 185px, Safari gives me 584px.

Comment: Can you replicate issue on jsFiddle? What kind of content the divs contain? Have you try using a CSS reset e.g: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ? Is this content static or dynamic?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vbs9mkms/4/ - here you have jsfiddle but... now it's work good...

Comment: I have it! I did not put this in jsfiddle but .cat-col-header have a transition and when page was in the process being loaded script get height of not fully width of element.

Comment: Don't hesitate to post it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`.cat-col-header` had a css transform property on .3s and when page was loading script first calculate height and then make transform to correct css width.

Example solution:

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    /* count what you want and watch out on Safari browser */
});
```

CSS:

```
body.loaded .cat-col-header {
   transition: .3s;
}
```